# JS return's undefined when is checked and I change select option selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox, undefined, html-select

I have a HTML JS code:

```
<form action="/resize" method="GET" name="resolutionForm">
 <select name="res" id="res" onchange="checkzoom(this.value); checkcut('centercropcheck')">
  <option value="original"> Original</option><option value="800x600">800x600</option>
 </select>
 <input type="checkbox" id="stretchcheck" name="stretch" onclick="verificastretch(this.id);">Esticar
 <div id="results">
  <span>original: </span>
  <span>200x200</span>
  <span>zoom: </span>
  <span>0x</span>
  <span id="zoom">0x</span></span>
 </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function elembyid(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
 }
 function checkzoom(v){
    if(v == '200x200' || v == 'original'){
        var zoom = '0x';
    }else{
        if(elembyid('stretchcheck').checked){
            verificastretch('stretchcheck');
        }else{
            var novow = Number(v.substr(0,v.lastIndexOf("x")));
            var novoh = Number(v.substr(v.lastIndexOf("x") +1, v.length));
            //alert('novow'+novow+'novoh'+novoh);
            var tamzoomw = novow / 200;
            var tamzoomh = novoh / 200;
            if(tamzoomw < tamzoomh){
                var zoom = (tamzoomw.length > 3? tamzoomw.toFixed(2) : tamzoomw)+'x';
            }else{
                var zoom = (tamzoomh.length > 3? tamzoomh.toFixed(2) : tamzoomh)+'x';
            }
        }
        elembyid('zoom').innerHTML = zoom;
    }
 }
 function verificastretch(id){
    var v = elembyid('res').value;
    if(v == '200x200' || v == 'original'){
        checkzoom(v);
    }else{
        if(elembyid(id).checked){
            //alert('aqui');
            var novow = Number(v.substr(0,v.lastIndexOf("x")));
            var novoh = Number(v.substr(v.lastIndexOf("x") +1, v.length));
            //alert('novow'+novow+'novoh'+novoh);
            var tamzoomw = novow / 200;
            var tamzoomh = novoh / 200;
            var zoom = (tamzoomw.length > 3? tamzoomw.toFixed(2) : tamzoomw)+'x '+(tamzoomh.length > 3? tamzoomh.toFixed(2) : tamzoomh)+'x';
            alert(zoom);
            elembyid('zoom').innerHTML = zoom;
        }else{
            checkzoom(v);
        }
    }
 }
</script>
```

When the stretch's checkbox is checked, and I change the selected option of select res, I get undefined in div id = "result", how can I solve this problem? 
In the file the code is without such ';' because the error occurred when copying.

Comment: There's a `;` to much in `var tamzoomw = novow;/ 200;` (within `verificastretch`). And `checkcut` is not defined.

Comment: In the file the code is without such ';' because the error occurred when copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the if-condition

```
        if(elembyid('stretchcheck').checked){
            verificastretch('stretchcheck');
        }else{
            …
        }
```

is finished and `verificastretch` has correctly set span `zoom` to `4x 3x`, span `zoom` is overwritten by an `undefined` variable `zoom`:

```
        elembyid('zoom').innerHTML = zoom;
```

I think you want that line within the else clause.

You could have found this by using a debugger and stepping through your code from function `checkzoom` onwards.

Comment: I understand that the variable zoom is undefined, but I do not understand why. In line with the command alert (zoom) the variable zoom is not indefinite. Why is it down soon? How can I fix this error?

Comment: @user2088749: Because of scoping: `zoom` within `verificastretch` is another variable than `zoom` in `checkzoom`. You can fix the error by moving the line `elembyid('zoom').innerHTML = zoom;` within the else clause, so it doesn't overwrite the span `zoom`, or you could return the zoom value from `verificastretch`.

Comment: I managed to solve by changing the line to the function checkzoom and returning the variable zoom function verificazoom. Thanks for the help.